# How to add column with dataframe if the dataframe is not empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that gets stock data and puts it in a dataframe. The functions is supposed to add a column to the df if the df is not empty.

The function looks like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame()

def get_ticker(TICKER, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, DATAFRAME, DF_TICKER):
    API_KEY = 'mbad9NhOd3PkFvk4gzkmVeoimAlKhgsyJ0NhsvqrkvGePvod0u51ufUWjIEZ'
    url = 'https://www.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/history?symbol=\
{}&date_from={}&date_to{}&sort=newest&api_token={}'.format(TICKER, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, API_KEY)

'''Makes a request to the API that returns a JSON-response '''

    r = requests.get(url)
    sample = json.loads(r.text)

'''Puts sample in Dataframe under each TICKER'''

    DF_TICKER = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=sample['history'],orient='index')
    cols = ['close']
    DF_TICKER = DF_TICKER[cols]
    DF_TICKER = DF_TICKER.rename(columns={'close':TICKER})
    if DATAFRAME.empty == True:
        DATAFRAME = DATAFRAME.append(DF_TICKER)
        print('First column')
    else:
        DATAFRAME = pd.concat(DATAFRAME, DF_TICKER, axis=1)
        print('Added another column')

get_ticker('AAPL', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', df, 'AAPL')
First column

get_ticker('GOOGL', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', df, 'GOOGL')
First column
```

Why is that the DATAFRAME.empty asserts to True even tho I previously have scraped down data for one ticker, say AAPL?

Comment: Where exactly in your code to you add any data to df?

Comment: The logic is that I have a df(DATEFRAME) that I want to add data to by creating temporare dataframes(DF_TICKER) and then if the df is empty it will append the temporary dataframe, and if a temporary dataframe has already been appended then it will concat the next temporary dataframe. Makes any sense?